# HttpClient Post request not sending post parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dotnet-httpclient

I'm sending a post request in my console application but it seems the it is unable to send the post parameters.
Here is my code:

```
static void HttpTest()
{
    string pass_url = "https://staging.fooddesk.be/api/v1/add_new_partner_pws";
    string postString = "[{\n\"product_name\": \"kip absrert\",\n\"producer_name\": \"Imperial Meat Products\",\n\"producer_art_num\": \"123\",\n\"supplier_name\": \"Vagro\",\n\"supplier_art_num\": \"12345\",\n\"ean_code\": \"5411153011327\",\n\"partner_art_nbr\": \"12345\"\n}]\"";
    var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("pws_data" ) , postString) ;
    Uri requestUri = new Uri(pass_url);
    using (var objClint = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        objClint.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", "ABCD");
        objClint.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-COMP-KEY", "XYZ");
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = objClint.PostAsync(requestUri, multipartContent).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an exception at line number 4.
Please let me know how should I send the post data in http client post request.

Comment: When you get "an exception" it is very helpful to post the exact message - usually that contains useful information

Comment: ... and as always: [you are using HttpClient wrong](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are mixing up your arguments in line 4.

Look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent.add?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_MultipartFormDataContent_Add_System_Net_Http_HttpContent_System_String_) for usage.

Try

```
multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(postString) , "pws_data") ;
```

Also, the post string has an extra quote at the end after ].  Removing that should help.

[{
"product_name": "kip absrert",
"producer_name": "Imperial Meat Products",
"producer_art_num": "123",
"supplier_name": "Vagro",
"supplier_art_num": "12345",
"ean_code": "5411153011327",
"partner_art_nbr": "12345"
}]"

Comment: Hi thanks, I updated that line and the exception is gone. 
But the other side of api is still not getting the posted parameter. 
Any clue ?

Comment: I get a 403 forbidden response.  Perhaps the API KEY or COMP KEY are not correct.

Comment: I now recieve a 400 Bad Request response.  I would delete your comment above with your API Key and Comp Key.

Comment: Yes it is returning 400 because pws_data is unavailable to other side.

Comment: string postString = "[{\n\"product_name\": \"kip absrert\",\n\"producer_name\": \"Imperial Meat Products\",\n\"producer_art_num\": \"123\",\n\"supplier_name\": \"Vagro\",\n\"supplier_art_num\": \"12345\",\n\"ean_code\": \"5411153011327\",\n\"partner_art_nbr\": \"12345\"\n}]\"";   At the end, after the ']' character, remove the \".   It is putting an extra double quote in the request.

Comment: Yes, working after updating the string. Thanks !